# In Firestore, how to ignore unwanted inputs for creation?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, serverless

As we all know we can create a record like this:

```
const docRef = db.collection('forms').add({
    name: 'Some name',
    address: 'Some address'
    userId: 'some user ID'
});
```

However, if some users (authenticated users) POST to your store:

```
const docRef = db.collection('forms').add({
    name: 'Some name',
    address: 'Some address'
    userId: 'some user ID',
    unwantedData1: 'xxx,
    unwantedData2: 'xxx,
    unwantedData3: 'xxx,
    unwantedData4: 'xxx,
    unwantedData5: 'xxx,
    unwantedData6: 'xxx,
    unwantedData6: 'xxx,
    ... // <- too many rubbish params
});
```

Although we have the security rule, however, some attackers can register a dummy account and do something like that. How to prevent this in Firestore?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Firestore Security Rules using [hasOnly](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasOnly).
You would do something like this:

```
allow write: if resource.data.keys().hasOnly([ <your whitelisted properties> ])
```

If for some reason you can't use the rules in this way, or you need to do more advanced checks, you could create a Cloud Function with a Firestore Trigger that validates the document and deletes it if something is wrong.

Comment: You're welcome! If you feel I answered your question, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I've just tested and it should be request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly([.....])..... anyway you saved me! Thanks!